# Why is Deedle casting a DataFrame boolean column into a float Series?

Tags: dataframe, f#, deedle

When I run the code below I get a `DataFrame` with one `bool` column and two `double` columns. However, when I extract the `bool`column as a Series the result is a Series object with types `DateTime` and `float`.

It looks like `Deedle` "cast" the column to another type.

Why is this happening?

```
open Deedle
let dates  = 
      [ DateTime(2013,1,1); 
        DateTime(2013,1,4); 
        DateTime(2013,1,8) ]

let values = [ 10.0; 20.0; 30.0 ]
let values2 = [ 0.0; -1.0; 1.0 ]


let first = Series(dates, values)
let second = Series(dates, values2)
let third: Series<DateTime,bool> = Series.map (fun k v -> v > 0.0) second

let df1 = Frame(["first"; "second"; "third"], [first; second; third])

let sb = df1.["third"]

df1;;
val it : Frame<DateTime,string> =
  Deedle.Frame`2[System.DateTime,System.String]
    {ColumnCount = 3;
     ColumnIndex = Deedle.Indices.Linear.LinearIndex`1[System.String];
     ColumnKeys = seq ["first"; "second"; "third"];
     ColumnTypes = seq [System.Double; System.Double; System.Boolean];
     ...

sb;;
val it : Series<DateTime,float> = ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the existing answer points out, `GetColumn` is the way to go. You can specify the generic parameter directly when calling `GetColumn` and avoid the type annotation to make the code nicer:

```
let sb = df1.GetColumn<bool>("third")
```

Deedle frame does not statically keep track of the types of the columns, so when you want to get a column as a typed series, you need to specify the type in some way.

We did not want to force people to write type annotations, because they tend to be quite long and ugly, so the primary way of getting a column is `GetColumn` where you can specify the type argument as in the above example.

The other ways of accessing column such as `df?third` and `df.["third"]` are shorthands that assume the column type to be `float` because that happens to be quite common scenario (at least for the most common uses of Deedle in finance), so these two notations give you a simpler way that "often works nicely".

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `.GetColumn` to extract the Series as a bool:

```
let sb':(Series<DateTime,bool>) = df1.GetColumn("third")
//val sb' : Series<DateTime,bool> =
//series [ 2013/01/01 0:00:00 => False; 2013/01/04 0:00:00 => False; 2013/01/08 0:00:00 => True]
```

As to your question of why, I haven't looked at the source, but I assume the type of indexer you use maybe returns an `obj`, then Deedle tries to cast it to something, or maybe it tries to cast everything to `float`.